# Github Actions: Required status check doesn't run due to files in paths not changed

Tags: github, github-actions

Let's say I have a pull request like this.

```
name: Workflow

on:
   pull_request:
     paths:
       - '**/*.h'
       - '**/*.c'
```

I protect the `master` branch by configuring GitHub Actions to require the status check to pass before the pull request is mergable.

Now I update a readme doc. I open a pull request against `master`. The pull request is unmergable because the status check never returns a success nor does it return a fail.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

The docs suggest creating another action with the same name, that runs when the opposite condition is met. In your case, you'd want

```
name: Workflow

on:
   pull_request:
     paths-ignore:
       - '**/*.h'
       - '**/*.c'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: 'echo "No build required" '
```

Notice the `paths-ignore`.

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/troubleshooting-required-status-checks#handling-skipped-but-required-checks

Comment: looks like the correct answer, but that seems like a terribly convoluted API from github

Comment: Is there a feature request yet for "require all status checks to pass that happen to be triggered"?

Comment: What if there are two files that change for example: foo.c and README.md?  Then both actions will trigger and the build check will pass from the path-ignore workflow while the other workflows "build" is still running.

Comment: @Steve sounds like the other answer has tested this and confirms it has the effect you anticipated, which IMO makes this approach kind of broken -- even though it's the official suggestion from GitHub, I'm still downvoting it (I feel a bit bad because quoting GitHub's docs really seems like it ought to be a foolproof way to produce a good answer to this question, but in this case it seems like it isn't)

Comment: it looks like the docs have now been changed, and no longer recommend this solution

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by the docs (Vicky's answer) doesn't work correctly for me. Providing multiple values for paths-ignore isn't preventing the generic/duplicate workflow from running. Since the original and the duplicate/generic workflow both run, we're still able to merge before the check finishes unfortunately.

This commit on Github shows a viable way of handling it that isn't too complicated:

https://github.com/android-password-store/Android-Password-Store/commit/0c45bffaba1192ea8a10173e709f439dbf32b089#diff-87ee5504a3e25ac558b343724c905f2f7949e8cec3d92b9c4300bb922afa164f

The relevant snippet (under "steps"):

```
    - name: Check if relevant files have changed
      uses: actions/github-script@0.9.0
      id: service-changed
      with:
        result-encoding: string
        script: |
          const result = await github.pulls.listFiles({
            owner: context.payload.repository.owner.login,
            repo: context.payload.repository.name,
            pull_number: context.payload.number,
            per_page: 100
          })
          const serviceChanged = result.data.filter(f => f.filename.startsWith("app/") || f.filename.endsWith("gradle") || f.filename.startsWith(".github") || f.filename.startsWith("gradle") || f.filename.endsWith("properties")).length > 0
          console.log(serviceChanged)
          return serviceChanged
    - name: Checkout repository
      if: ${{ steps.service-changed.outputs.result == 'true' }}
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Copy CI gradle.properties
      if: ${{ steps.service-changed.outputs.result == 'true' }}
      run: mkdir -p ~/.gradle ; cp .github/ci-gradle.properties ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

Here are some other options I've found that look less viable or much more complicated:

- https://github.com/fkirc/skip-duplicate-actions Looks questionable at solving this particular problem
- https://brunoscheufler.com/blog/2022-04-24-required-github-actions-jobs-in-a-monorepo Looks awfully complicated but viable
- https://blog.pantsbuild.org/skipping-github-actions-jobs-without-breaking-branch-protection/ Looks complicated, and it turns into a sales pitch

Comment: The fact that GitHub's official docs suggest an IMO wildly broken solution is quite a surprise to me. I submitted the feedback thing at the bottom of the page but I'm not sure if that will reach anyone. Would be grateful if someone highlighted a support thread with them or something.

Comment: (looks like GitHub's docs have changed and no longer recommend the other answer)